# How can i round corners of container table view?

Tags: ios, xcode5, uitableview, cornerradius, uicontainerview

I have a main view controller. It contains a table view controller ( in a container ) , i want to round out the tableview so it shows similarly to the facebook login one.

Code i have used in the child view controller ( which is a tableview controller ) in viewDidLoad :

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.tableView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Result :

[image]

As you can see , when the field is selected , the corners SEEM rounded , but the white space remains. How can i make them rounded even when it isn't selected ?

Using : XCODE 5 , IOS 7

Comment: Have you tried applying it to the superlayer instead?

Comment: If you mean self.tableview.superview.layer.cornerradius = x , doesn't work , just tried it .

Comment: What about view.layer.superlayer?

Comment: Have you tried a for loop to set all the sublayers corner radius? That may do it

Comment: Could you write the code as an answer or here so i can try it ? I assume i would use the loop in the parent view controller.

Comment: See my answer with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you requested me to do, here is the code you wanted:

```
for (CALayer *subLayer in self.tableView.layer.sublayers)
{
    subLayer.cornerRadius = 10;
    subLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm grateful there are smarter people than my out there , thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@interface CustomtableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UITextField * username;
    UIButton * submit;
}

@implementation CustomtableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 300, 45)];
    submit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [submit setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[submit setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.56] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [submit setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [submit.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [submit setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 15.0, 280.0, 44.0)];
    [newView addSubview:submit];

    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:newView];

   [super viewDidLoad];

}

  #pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake( 10,  320);
        [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50,0,0,0)];
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
        username.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        username.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            username.placeholder = @"example@gmail.com";
            username.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
            username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Username";
            username.clearButtonMode = YES;
        }
        else {
            username.placeholder = @"minimum 6 characters";
            username.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            username.secureTextEntry = YES;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Password";
            username.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        }
        username.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        username.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
        username.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
        username.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        username.tag = 0;


        username.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways; // no clear 'x' button to the right
        [username setEnabled: YES];


    [cell.contentView addSubview: username];

         }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Here, i've created just two textfields for username and password. You can use the else if condition to insert any no of textfields in each of the successive rows according to your needs.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User Login"];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 50;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return @"";

}
```

So, my code here is just used for creating a login page with two textfields(Username and Password) and a Login button. You can modify my code according to your needs. Cheers!

Comment: I don't want to rewrite the whole controller , the corners are getting rounded but it isn't clipped. There has to be a simpler solution.